Errors when signing and sending transaction with Ethers
I get the error in the browser console when the function attempt to execute signTransaction, even though the transaction was successfully broadcasted to the blockchain. The loading variable never get set to false which is when the function ends it executions.
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: invalid BytesLike value (argument="value", value={ "_type": "TransactionResponse", "accessList": null, "blobVersionedHashes": null, "blockHash": null, "blockNumber": null, "chainId": null, "data": "0x3f4a5d0a00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000e0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000012000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000066a5e97e00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000067064736b6a6600000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006717064776a6600000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000966616473662e636f6d0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000", "from": "0xc768B39DBcBCCfD6dECae24b0a591e78BEA3382F", "gasLimit": "203181", "gasPrice": "35133400011", "hash": "0x9c31df9f6bd4778fbdd32f0438711a3d555f2482094275235069e4b6221f66ee", "index": null, "maxFeePerBlobGas": null, "maxFeePerGas": "35133400011", "maxPriorityFeePerGas": "35133399990", "nonce": 23, "signature": { "_type": "signature", "networkV": null, "r": "0x7c377e75a739b7f81a2e148641e5b577e32c5fb592d0bbe0d42a2ac76be9e038", "s": "0x4e62a1e353b4aeb5645f8bae9325e8661e841f9a354cd851314923b1fd28f3b5", "v": 27 }, "to": "0x0Bc1FcA0bC7b0B06fDa8DB3A1Cb0504A06404923", "type": 2, "value": "0" }, code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=6.13.1)

'use client'

import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useData } from "../../contexts/DataContext";
import { usePrivy, useWallets } from "@privy-io/react-auth";

const Admin = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const { goMarket, loadBlockchainData, account, walletSigner, feeData, provider } = useData!();
  const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(false);

  const [title, setTitle] = React.useState("");
  const [description, setDescription] = React.useState("");
  const [category, setCategory] = React.useState("");
  const [url, setURL] = React.useState("");
  const [timestamp, setTimestamp] = React.useState<
    string | number | readonly string[] | undefined
  >(Date());

  useEffect(() => {
    loadBlockchainData();
  }, [loading, account]);

  const handleSubmit = async () => {
    setLoading(true);

    let dateInWeek = new Date();
    dateInWeek.setDate(dateInWeek.getDate() + 7);
    const deadline = Math.floor(dateInWeek.getTime() / 1000);
    setTimestamp(deadline);

    const gasLimit = await goMarket.createMarket.estimateGas(title, description, category, url, timestamp);

    const tx = {
      from: walletSigner.address,
      to: goMarket.target,
      gas: gasLimit,
      nonce: await walletSigner.getNonce(),
      maxPriorityFeePerGas: feeData.maxPriorityFeePerGas.toString(),
      maxFeePerGas: feeData.maxFeePerGas.toString(),
      chainId: 80002,
      // data: goMarket.interface.encodeFunctionData('createMarket', [title, description, category, url, timestamp])
      data: await goMarket.createMarket(title, description, category, url, timestamp)
    };

    const signedTx = await walletSigner.signTransaction(tx);
    const sentTx = await provider.broadcastTransaction(signedTx);

    await sentTx.wait();

    setLoading(false);
    setTitle("");
    setDescription("");
    setCategory("");
    setURL("");
    setTimestamp(undefined);
    router.push("/");
  };
};

export default Admin;

I have tried to encode the data to be sent, but the transaction was unsuccessful.
data: goMarket.interface.encodeFunctionData('createMarket', [title, description, category, url, timestamp]), therefore, I used contract.METHOD_NAME to send the data.

I see you are setting the loading variable to true and false in the same function.
In ReactJS, setter functions for state (like setState in class components or the state updater functions returned by useState in functional components) are asynchronous. This means that when you call a setter function to update the state, React doesn’t immediately update the state. Instead, it schedules the update to be performed later, usually after the current function has finished executing. Here are some key reasons for this behavior:
1.  Batching for Performance: React batches multiple state updates together to improve performance. By scheduling updates instead of executing them immediately, React can minimize the number of re-renders, leading to better performance. This is especially important in larger applications where frequent re-renders can be costly.
2.  Avoiding Inconsistent States: If state updates were applied immediately, subsequent lines of code in the same function could see an inconsistent or intermediate state. By deferring the update, React ensures that all state updates within the same event cycle are processed together, maintaining consistency.
3.  Predictable Behavior: This asynchronous behavior makes the state management more predictable. It helps ensure that the component re-renders only after all the updates have been processed, which simplifies reasoning about the state and the component’s behavior.

Hence, your setLoading() is not executing as you expect it to be.
Adjust your logic such that you have setLoading(true) and setLoading(false) in two different functions.

Would making refreshStates function which will include setLoading(false) and all the other states set to null and calling at the the end of handleSubmit function, be a good solution?

But even if you are calling refreshStates function at the end of the handleSubmit, it would essentially be like doing the function inside handleSubmit itself, right?
let me see if I can edit the answer to give a better solution.
